# splitting arrays

Tags: java

How do I partition an array into four sub arrays in Java?

Comment: See my answer here:

[Splits an array in multiple arrays with a specific maximum size][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731042/split-array-into-two-parts-without-for-loop-in-java/12590378#12590378

Answer (score 11):

Create 2 Array of the length you want to have it.

And use

```
System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)
```

to copy the values from the original to the two new target arraies.

Example:

```
    int[] original = new int [13];
    int[] a = new int[3];
    int[] b = new int[10];

    System.arraycopy(original, 0, a, 0, 3);
    System.arraycopy(original, 3, b, 0, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary partitioning... I would use one of the two ways below:

1. If you need to move groups of items into separate arrays, for example items 0 to 10 to array 1, 11 to 20 to array 2 etc., I would create four arrays and use `System.arraycopy()` static method:

   ```
   System.arraycopy(sourceArray, sourceStart, destArray, destStart, length);
   ```
2. If you must check, where a particular item should go, create four arrays, four index counter variables and make a loop through the elements of the original array. Test the condition and add it to one of the four arrays, incrementing the appropriate index counter.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what was already said, you could use one of the [Arrays.copyOfRange(...)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(boolean[],%20int,%20int)) methods available in class `java.util.Arrays`.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here:

[Split an array in multiple arrays with a specific maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731042/split-array-into-two-parts-without-for-loop-in-java/12590378#12590378)

What's the maximum size you have to evaluate by dividing the array length by the number of sub arryas (beware of float results, it must be an Integer).