# Dividing an array list into two equal parts

Tags: java, arraylist

I was wondering if there is a way (simple way hopefully) to take the elements of an array list and put it into 2 other array lists. If the original array list contained ten numbers, is there a way to split the array list in half giving 5 numbers to each new array list? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731042/split-array-into-two-parts-without-for-loop-in-java

Comment: Can you be more specific?  For example, can you show us what you've tried?  It's a lot easier to fix well-defined problems.

Comment: Use my code it works for odd as well even list size   
int listSize = listOfArtist.size();
   int mid = 0;

   if (listSize % 2 == 0) {

    mid = listSize / 2;

    Log.e("Parting", "You entered an even number. mid " + mid
      + " size is " + listSize);

   } else {

    mid = (listSize + 1) / 2;

    Log.e("Parting", "You entered an odd number. mid " + mid
      + " size is " + listSize);

   }

   leftArray = new ArrayList<ArtistModel>(listOfArtist.subList(0, mid));

   rightArray = new ArrayList<ArtistModel>(listOfArtist.subList(mid,
     listSize));

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method:

`newArrList = arrayYouWantToSplit.subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex);`

Comment: Does it split the original list into two seperate lists?

Comment: obviously yea, It seems that you may not understand what a sub list or index means.