# An Array of Doubles from Two Arrays of Strings

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Say I have two arrays:

```
let arrayOne = ["Hi", "Hi", "Hello", "Not Hey", "Howdy", "Hi"]
let arrayTwo = ["Hi", "Hello", "Hey", "Not Howdy", "Hi", "Hi"]
```

and I have this for loop that gets the percent similarity of the doubles:

```
var matches = 0

for (index, item) in enumerate(arrayOne) {
    if item == arrayTwo[index] {
        matches++
    }
}
```

However, what if those arrays are longer and I want data points of those similarities instead of one single calculation. What kind of a function could I write where it takes the first 5 elements off the array, returns their similarity with the for loop, and moves on to the next 5? ie. it would be a function that takes two string arrays and returns an array of doubles. I am sure this is a simple question but I do not know how to approach taking 5 array elements at a time and then returning an array of doubles (like data points the the string array similarities).

Comment: Have a look at using `Sets` instead of arrays.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589181/set-operations-union-intersection-on-swift-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this.  I think it does what you are asking.  By introducing a `count` variable to keep track of the number of items you have processed, you will know when to update your `counts` array:

```
var matches = 0

let arrayOne = ["Hi", "Hi", "Hello", "Not Hey", "Howdy", "Hi", "a", "b", "c"]
let arrayTwo = ["Hi", "Hello", "Hey", "Not Howdy", "Hi", "Hi", "a", "B", "C"]

var count = 0
var counts:[Int] = []

for (index, item) in enumerate(arrayOne) {
    if item == arrayTwo[index] {
        matches++
    }
    // Have we done 5?  If so, time to update counts array
    if ++count == 5 {
        counts.append(matches)
        count = 0
        matches = 0
    }
}
// If we didn't have 5, just append the matches for the remaining items
if count > 0 {
    counts.append(matches)
}

println(counts)  // prints "[1, 2]"
```

Answer (score 4):

I’m not clear quite what you’re asking, however, you *might* find playing around with `zip`, `map`, and `reduce` helpful.

For example, you could rewrite your original loop like this (assuming Swift 2.0, you’d have to rearrange slightly for 1.2):

```
zip(arrayOne, arrayTwo).reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.0 == $1.1 ? 1 : 0) }
// returns 4
```

`zip` creates a new sequence of the pairs of elements at each corresponding position.

`reduce` takes a starting value, then keeps a running value by applying a function to the current value and the next value in the sequence – bearing in mind this is a sequence of pair elements, you want to add 1 when they are the same, 0 when they aren’t.  This then gives you a count of the positions where both match.

If instead you wanted an array, with true representing a match at that point, and false if different, you could use `map`:

```
zip(arrayOne, arrayTwo).map(==)
// returns [true, false, false, false, false, true]
```

If on the other hand you wanted a list of the differences in string length between the two strings at each position, you could change it to:

```
zip(arrayOne, arrayTwo).map { (a,b) in
    a.characters.count - b.characters.count 
}
// returns [0, -3, 2, -2, 3, 0]
```

As some have suggested, `Set` might help, e.g.:

```
let commonElements = Set(arrayOne).intersect(arrayTwo)
// returns strings present in both e.g. {"Hi", "Hello”}
```

This is a good approach if you are OK treating your data as a set i.e. order doesn’t matter and duplicates can be ignored. If order and dupes do matter, you probably have to stick with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Right - so I think I understand what you're looking for: you want to have a `matches` function like the one you've written that works for chunks of a certain number of elements. First off, you're going to need a chunk function. There's a good discussion of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185492/split-large-array-in-array-of-two-elements/31185663#31185663), but they're for arrays, and you're going to want to zip your two arrays together here, so you'll need one for `SequenceType`. This works:

````
public extension SequenceType {

  /// Returns an array of arrays of n non-overlapping elements of self
  /// - Parameter n: The size of the chunk
  ///  ```swift
  ///  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].chunk(2)
  ///
  ///  [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
  /// ```

  func chunk(_ n: Int) -> [[Generator.Element]] {
    var g = self.generate()
    var ret: [[Generator.Element]] = [[]]
    while let next = g.next() {
      if ret.last!.count < n {
        ret[ret.endIndex.predecessor()].append(next)
      } else {
        ret.append([next])
      }
    }
    return ret
  }
}
````

Then, you need a function that counts the matches in two arrays. You could inline it with a closure, or you could define it separately, it doesn't make much of a difference.

```
func matchesEvery<
  S0 : SequenceType,
  S1 : SequenceType,
  T  : Equatable where
  S0.Generator.Element == T,
  S1.Generator.Element == T
  >(_ n: Int, s0: S0, s1: S1) -> [Int] {
    return zip(s0, s1)
      .chunk(5)
      .map { $0.reduce(0) { $1.0 == $1.1 ? $0 + 1 : $0 } }
}
```

That will return:

```
let arrayOne = ["Hi", "Hi", "Hello", "Not Hey", "Howdy", "Hi"]
let arrayTwo = ["Hi", "Hello", "Hey", "Not Howdy", "Hi", "Hi"]

matchesEvery(5, s0: arrayOne, s1: arrayTwo) // [1, 1]
```

Since in the first five there's one match, and in the last there is one as well.