# Grouping an Array in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to parse a string into an N × M array of array of characters. For example - given the following:

```
let string = "ABCDEF" + "GHIJKL" + "MNOPQR"
```

I'd like to convert to this:

```
[
  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
  ["G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"],
  ["M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R"],
]
```

I noticed using `Array(string.characters)` gives me a one dimension array. Does a Swift function exist to group a one dimensional array? Is it possible to convert the string directly into a multi dimensional array?

Comment: Are you having 3 different string `ABCDEF`, `GHIJKL` and `MNOPQR`.

Comment: @NiravD nope - that's just to show how the split happens - one string.

Comment: @Stussa You want to split your string with 6 character range?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185492/split-large-array-in-array-of-two-elements for a quite general solution to split an array into chunks of a given size.

Comment: Using the chunk method from http://stackoverflow.com/a/31185663/1187415 this becomes simply `Array(string.characters.chunk(5))`